# Can the email header for announcements be changed?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to modify the email header for answers.ros.org that announces new questions and answers?  I just have everything forwarded to my email, and I'd prefer threading to work properly, but the headers are different enough that gmail does not thread them together, so I have 2 threads now for every topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9121/can-the-email-header-for-announcements-be-changed?/) by [Andrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/117/andrew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-02-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes that can be done.  Please file a ticket here https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket?component=answers.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2011-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-21**:
I opened a ticket https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3352